# iOS: Detect GPS service availability programmatically within an app

Tags: ios, iphone, gps, settings, cllocation

I want to attach a listener in IOS which is invoked whenever **GPS is turned ON or OFF from settings**. Listener should be invoked no matter my application is running, in background or has been stopped. I have this functionality that i need to keep GPS settings of a user who has installed app, on server side, so whenever GPS is changed i must notify the server.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there is no such notification exists.

However you can create and start a timer (`NSTimer`) that will regularly poll whether GPS is enabled or not, using ['CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled'](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW31) method.

Within your class, you can have a bool iVar that will be set / reset based on return value. Whenever its value is altered, you can notify server about service start / stoppage.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there isn't any listener,

You can Use **Delegate** method of CLLocationManager.

Use this delegate method for getting location `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations`

Form this [locations lastObject] you can latest location send location to server.

You can not get location when app is stopped.